# Tensorflow's Image Recognition Tutorial gives same answer

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition

I was working around with Tensorflow's Image Recognition tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition)

It gave me the right answer when i run

```
    python classify_image.py
```

But when I run

```
    python classify_image.py --cat.jpg
```

It returns the same answer as before. I did put the image in the imagenet folder (same as classify_image.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the argument in a wrong way. Try:

```
python classify_image.py --image_file cat.jpg
```